# how to calculate the distinct average of a field in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have to calculate 3 fields, max, me and avg, but the avg needs to be the equivalent of avg(distinct(vl)) in sql, how to do this in a single pyspark dataframe?

```
df = df1.groupBy("cd","name")\
.agg(avg(col("tx_m")).alias("avg"),\
min(col("tx_vl")).alias("min"),\
max(col("tx_vl")).alias("max"))
```

Any ideas to make this distinct in avg, please?

Comment: you can use `sumDistinct()/countDistinct()` instead of the `avg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `sumDistinct()/countDistinct()` instead of the direct `avg()` in aggregation. Here's an example.

```py
data_sdf. \
    agg(func.sum('nums').alias('sum'),
        func.count('nums').alias('count'),
        func.avg('nums').alias('avg'),
        func.sumDistinct('nums').alias('sum_distinct'),
        func.countDistinct('nums').alias('count_distinct'),
        (func.sumDistinct('nums') / func.countDistinct('nums')).alias('avg_distinct')
        ). \
    show()

# +----+-----+-----+------------+--------------+-----------------+
# | sum|count|  avg|sum_distinct|count_distinct|     avg_distinct|
# +----+-----+-----+------------+--------------+-----------------+
# |1081|   25|43.24|         988|            21|47.04761904761905|
# +----+-----+-----+------------+--------------+-----------------+
```